# Compilation error using googletest's EXPECT_NO_THROW with std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest, stdarray

I got this error while trying to work with std::array in googletest. Following is a minimal example that produces this error:

arr.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <array>

TEST(Test, Positive) {
    EXPECT_NO_THROW({
        const std::array<unsigned char, 16> foo = {1, 2, 3};
    });
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I used the [current googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest/commit/5e7fd50e17b6edf1cadff973d0ec68966cf3265e) code from github. To make & make install googletest.

As a compiler I used clang3.8 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Using the follownig command:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -o arr arr.cpp
```

Results in:

```
arr.cpp:6:41: error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
        const std::array<unsigned char, 16> blasdasd = {1, 2, 3};
                                        ^
/usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h:1845:9: note: macro 'EXPECT_NO_THROW' defined here
#define EXPECT_NO_THROW(statement) \
        ^
arr.cpp:5:5: note: cannot use initializer list at the beginning of a macro argument
    EXPECT_NO_THROW({
    ^               ~
arr.cpp:5:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EXPECT_NO_THROW'
    EXPECT_NO_THROW({
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

Removing the EXPECT_NO_THROW macro and simply declaring the array compiles fine. Is there anything obvious I am missing or should I file a bug report on github?

Comment: Macros do not understand C++, and especially `<,>` templates and commas inside template arguments.  Those commas are being parsed as multiple arguments to the macro.  As a first pass, `using uchar_16_array = std::array<unsigned char, 16>` and use `uchar_16_array` in the macro.  I assume it will understand the initializer list (but cannot guarantee it)

Comment: You can use another set of parentheses to work around the problem Yakk mentioned: `EXPECT_NO_THROW(( ... ));` This will pass any code in the `...` as a single argument to the macro.

Comment: @dyp, Unfortunately, the extra parens are still carried through, so it's possible that they'll break the replacement text if the macro doesn't handle them.

Comment: @chris Not entirely sure I understand what you mean, but I realized gtest is expecting an actual statement in that context (which it ends itself with a `;`), so enclosing the statement in parenthesis will of course not work directly. However, you can wrap the statement in a lambda and pass that enclosed in parenthesis: `EXPECT_NO_THROW(( [&]{ my_code; }() ));`

Comment: I strongly recommend you enable warnings when compiling: `-Wall -Wextra` They can be bothersome at first, but they enable important messages from the compiler about unintended consequences of your program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `EXPECT_NO_THROW` is a macro defined as follows:

```
#define EXPECT_NO_THROW(statement) \
  GTEST_TEST_NO_THROW_(statement, GTEST_NONFATAL_FAILURE_)
```

As you can see, this is a function-like macro which takes one argument. The preprocessor (which deals with macros) works on tokens. It does not understand C++, nor C, but only its own token language. (Nowadays, compilation and preprocessing happen in one stage apparently, but I'm referring to the semantics of the preprocessor language.)

The preprocessor expects a single argument for `EXPECT_NO_THROW`. It separates arguments for function-like macros by looking for commas. So when it sees a list of tokens in the argument list for a function-like macro such as:

```
EXPECT_NO_THROW( const std::array<unsigned char, 16> foo = {1, 2, 3}; )
```

then it separates the argument list into arguments as follows:

- `const std::array<unsigned char`
- `16> foo = {1`
- `2`
- `3};`

And these are of course multiple arguments where one is expected for the function-like macro `EXPECT_NO_THROW`.

---

In order to pass several preprocessing tokens including `,` as a single argument to a function-like macro, you can enclose those tokens in parentheses:

```
EXPECT_NO_THROW( (const std::array<unsigned char, 16> foo = {1, 2, 3};) );
```

However, this will not compile:

The `EXPECT_NO_THROW` macro is expanded as follows:

```
#define GTEST_TEST_NO_THROW_(statement, fail) \
  GTEST_AMBIGUOUS_ELSE_BLOCKER_ \
  if (::testing::internal::AlwaysTrue()) { \
    try { \
      GTEST_SUPPRESS_UNREACHABLE_CODE_WARNING_BELOW_(statement); \
    } \
    catch (...) { \
      goto GTEST_CONCAT_TOKEN_(gtest_label_testnothrow_, __LINE__); \
    } \
  } else \
    GTEST_CONCAT_TOKEN_(gtest_label_testnothrow_, __LINE__): \
      fail("Expected: " #statement " doesn't throw an exception.\n" \
           "  Actual: it throws.")
```

Where the unreachable code macro is defined as follows:

```
#define GTEST_SUPPRESS_UNREACHABLE_CODE_WARNING_BELOW_(statement) \
  if (::testing::internal::AlwaysTrue()) { statement; }
```

So, if you put a statement `STMT` inside the `EXPECT_NO_THROW` macro, you'll end up with:

```
  if (::testing::internal::AlwaysTrue()) {
    try {
      if (::testing::internal::AlwaysTrue()) { STMT; };
    }
  // ...
```

Therefore, if you put `(STMT;)` into `EXPECT_NO_THROW`, you end up with a line

```
if (::testing::internal::AlwaysTrue()) { (STMT;); };
```

The part `(STMT;);` is not legal C++. Neither is `(STMT);` if that `STMT` is a declaration as in the OP.

If you pass `({STMT;})` into the macro, you'll end up with `({STMT;});` which is still illegal in C++, but it's allowed in g++ as an extension; it's an *expression-statement*. Here, the `{STMT;}` part is interpreted as an expression, enclosed in parentheses to form the expression `({STMT;})`.

You can also try to isolate the commas. As [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk) pointed out in a comment to the OP, you can hide the comma in the template-argument list by using a typedef; the remaining commas in the initializer-list can be wrapped by using a temporary, for example:

```
using array_t = std::array<unsigned char, 16>;
EXPECT_NO_THROW( const array_t foo = (array_t{1, 2, 3}); );
```

---

While the original `EXPECT_NO_THROW(STMT)` does allow `STMT` to be a statement, statements in C++ cannot be arbitrarily enclosed in parentheses. Expressions however can be arbitrarily enclosed in parentheses, and expressions can be used as a statement. This is why passing the statement as an expression-statement works. If we can formulate our array declaration as an expression, this will solve the problem:

```
EXPECT_NO_THROW(( std::array<unsigned char, 16>{1, 2, 3} ));
```

Notice this creates a temporary array; this is not a declaration-statement as in the OP, but a single expression.

But it might not always be this simple to create an expression of the things we want to test. However, there's one expression in standard C++ which can contain statements: A lambda-expression.

```
EXPECT_NO_THROW(( []{ const std::array<unsigned char, 16> foo = {1, 2, 3}; }() ));
```

Please note the `()` after the lambda which is important to actually execute the statement within the lamdba! Forgetting this is a very subtle source of errors :(

Comment: Once we get the [`source_location` class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location), we can get rid of this macro mess by just passing the lambda to a function template. This also gets rid of the explicit manual `()` to call the lambda.

Answer (score 2):

So as many of you pointed out in the comments that macros and template don't work well together. Is this limitation of googletest documented in the docs? I can't find anything hinting at such a limitation.

If you do have more workarounds please provide them and I'll add them to my answer, of I you do have a real answer please share :)

In the following I tried the proposed solutions, and compiled them using:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -o arr arr.cpp -lgtest_main -lgtest -lpthread
```

Extra braces around the EXPECT_NO_THROW argument does **work**:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <array>

TEST(Test, Positive) {
    EXPECT_NO_THROW(({
        const std::array<unsigned char, 16> foo = {1, 2, 3};
    }));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Provide a using declaration does **not work**:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <array>

using uchar_16_arr = std::array<unsigned char, 16>;

TEST(Test, Positive) {
    EXPECT_NO_THROW({
        const uchar_16_arr foo = {1, 2, 3};
    });
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

As it still results in the same error message:

```
arr.cpp:8:38: error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
        const uchar_16_arr foo = {1, 2, 3};
                                     ^
/usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h:1845:9: note: macro 'EXPECT_NO_THROW' defined here
#define EXPECT_NO_THROW(statement) \
        ^
arr.cpp:7:5: note: cannot use initializer list at the beginning of a macro argument
    EXPECT_NO_THROW({
    ^               ~
arr.cpp:7:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EXPECT_NO_THROW'
    EXPECT_NO_THROW({
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: I think the reason why the using-declaration doesn't work is that `{` does not have special meaning in the preprocessor, hence everything up to the first `,` is considered the first macro argument. On the other hand, `(` and `)` have special meaning in the preprocessor (specifically, in macro-replacement): The separation of arguments for the macro looks for `,` except within parentheses.